# Valor "menor que" seja removido

Tags: php, dom

Olá, fiz uma aplicação para rodar localmente em PHP, porém estou querendo dar uma incrementada, para que seja mais rápida. Não sou programador, fiz essa aplicação, vendo alguns exemplos na internet. Tenho esta parte de um código que pegas após pegar alguns dados de um site por CURL:

```
//Pega os valores da uasg
$numsuasg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach ($numsuasg as $numuasg) {
$uasg[] = $numuasg->nodeValue . "\n";
}
$uasg = array_map('trim', $uasg); // remove os espaços em branco
$newuasg = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $uasg);//remove caracteres não numericos do output
$newuasg = array_filter($newuasg, function($elemento){
return $elemento > 999;
});
$newuasg = array_slice($newuasg, 2);
print_r($newuasg);
```

O resultado retorna:

```
Array ( [0] => 22017 [1] => 160270 [2] => 2 [3] => 62017 [4] => 135026 [5] 
=> 82017 [6] => 150154 [7] => 102017 [8] => 154040 [9] => 102017 [10] => 
925611 [11] => 132017 [12] => 153073 [13] => 162017 [14] => 154419 [15] => 
192017 [16] => 160536 [17] => 61 [18] => 192017 [19] => 158126 [20] => 
212017 [21] => 158658 [22] => 242017 [23] => 153065 [24] => 252017 [25] => 
135023 [26] => 252017 [27] => 926334 [28] => 332017 [29] => 257003 [30] => 
352017 [31] => 153251 [32] => 372017 [33] => 155009 [34] => 392017 [35] => 
765720 [36] => 512017 [37] => 153033 [38] => 552017 [39] => 153165 [40] => 
842017 [41] => 155124 [42] => 842017 [43] => 158516 [44] => 1642017 [45] => 
153080 [46] => 2072017 [47] => 153054 [48] => 4202017 [49] => 150232 [50] => 
5612017 [51] => 943001 [52] => 8852017 [53] => 943001 [54] => 9382017 [55] 
=> 943001 [56] => 10072017 [57] => 943001 )
```

Gostaria de saber como retiro valores menores que 4 caracteres, como por exemplo na posição [2] => 2, para ela não exista, e a posição [2] seria 62017 (que está na posição 3).
Eu já pesquisei em vários lugares e não encontrei nada que pudesse me indicar um caminho para resolver isso. lembrando que os resultados são variáveis, mudam a todo tempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para retirar valores menores que `4` carateres pode utilizar a função `array_filter` que já está a utilizar passando uma função com a lógica apropriada. Uma vez que os valores do array são numéricos filtrar a `4` casas irá corresponder a ficar apenas com os elementos superiores a 999.

Exemplo:

```
$newuasg = array_filter($newuasg, function($elemento){
    return $elemento > 999;
});
```

[Veja está lógica a ser aplicada no Ideone](https://ideone.com/zVlv0J)

Está também a aplicar um mapeamento de cada valor para o `trim` desse mesmo valor dentro do `foreach`, que acaba por processar os mesmos elementos várias vezes. Em vez disso deve fazer esse mapeamento apenas uma vez e a seguir ao `foreach`

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, sua modificação no array_filter funcionou, porém não entendi o que você falou na segunda parte.

Comment: @agora Sem problema. Referia-me especificamente a `$uasg = array_map('trim', $uasg);` que está dento do `foreach` e devia passar para depois de forma a não fazer processamento desnecessário. É apenas uma pequena melhoria no código em si. Como está acaba por aplicar o trim aos mesmos elementos várias vezes.

Comment: Seria algo assim: <br/>                                                                    
    $numsuasg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($numsuasg as $numuasg) {
    $uasg[] = $numuasg->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
    $uasg = array_map('trim', $uasg); // remove os espaços em branco
    $newuasg = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $uasg);   // remove caracteres 
    não numericos do output
    $newuasg = array_filter($newuasg, function($elemento){return $elemento > 999;
});
$newuasg = array_slice($newuasg, 2);
print_r($newuasg);

Comment: @JohnPabloMartins Sim dessa forma, como está na pergunta